# Cannot recovery key in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, keystore

I want build and generate my android project, and i use my `keystore` file. but when build app show me this error : 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Change the keystore for a diferent password to the key password.

Open a CMD prompt in key.jks location, then change a keystore password:

```
keytool -storepasswd -keystore keyName.jks
Enter keystore password: (Old Keystore)
New keystore password: (New Keystore)
Re-enter new keystore password: (Re-enter new Keystore)
```

Now change the key password for a diferent password:

```
keytool -keypasswd -keystore key.jks -alias key
Enter keystore password: (The new Keystore you recently changed)
New key password for <key>: (New diferent key password)
Re-enter new key password for <key>: (Re-enter new diferent key password)
```